# Extract 95% confidence interval values from kaplan meier model

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival

After computing a kaplan meier model I get the `km_fit` list below. How can I extract 95% confidence interval values now?

```
# Plot Kaplan-Meier curves
sg1_survival <- Surv(
  time = sg1$`Time from breast cancer diagnosis to bone metastasis (months) (NA = unknown)`,
  event = sg1$`status (=1 as all pts have bone metastasis and BC)`
)


km_fit <- survfit(sg1_survival ~ sg1$`Molecular type (0=hr+her2+, 1=hr+her2-, 2=hr-her2+, 3=TNBC)`, data = sg1)

# Calculate 95% confidence intervals? fails with "no applicable method"
ci <- confint(km_fit, level = 0.95)
```

Comment: That’s a very strange RHS of the formula in the survfit call. It’s an error-prone practice to use $ in R formulas.

Comment: You don't need most of those extra packages, in fact I think you only need `survival` to make your code work. Removing them makes your code more likely for people to try and run it.

Comment: Are you looking for `summary(km_fit)$lower; summary(km_fit)$upper`, or `km_fit$lower; km_fit$upper`?

Comment: @IRTFM actually using `data$column` is less error prone because a model specified as `x~y` will get `y` from the enclosing environment if you meant to use `Y` as a column name. Of course then R's partial name matching will bite, so the real "minimal error prone" solution is like `glm( foo[["name of this"]] ~ foo[["name of that"]])`...

Comment: It's likely to screw up later processing of the model object in either case because the environment of the model is established by the `data` argument . It's even a bad idea to create the Surv(.) argument outside the `survfit` or other survival regression functions. At least that's what I was taught by Terry Therneau. In spatial modeling I will listen to you. In survival modeling I listen to Terry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in `km_fit`.

```
km_fit <- survfit(sg1_survival ~ sg1$`Molecular type (0=hr+her2+, 1=hr+her2-, 2=hr-her2+, 3=TNBC)`, data = sg1)
c <- data.frame(km_fit$time, km_fit$lower, km_fit$upper) 
c
```

```
 sum.time  sum.lower sum.upper
1  28.37260 0.29950713         1
2  34.15890 0.06727839         1
3 137.32603         NA        NA
4  14.00548 0.12504883         1
5  75.02466         NA        NA
```

Comment: You don't need the summary call, those objects are in the fitted object

Comment: You're right. You could just call ```km_fit```. You could build a data.frame from ```km_fit$lower``` etc to simplify it. Good call.

Comment: The `Surv` function doesn't seem to document this anywhere but its such an old and stable piece of code its not going to change, unlike other newer functions that manipulate fitted model objects...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the broom package as below and check `conf.high & conf.low`

```r
new_km_fit <- broom::tidy(km_fit)


# A tibble: 5 × 9
   time n.risk n.event n.censor estimate std.error conf.high conf.low strata                         
  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                          
1  28.4      3       1        0    0.667     0.408         1   0.300  sg1$`Molecular type (0=hr+her2…
2  34.2      2       1        0    0.333     0.816         1   0.0673 sg1$`Molecular type (0=hr+her2…
3 137.       1       1        0    0       Inf            NA  NA      sg1$`Molecular type (0=hr+her2…
4  14.0      2       1        0    0.5       0.707         1   0.125  sg1$`Molecular type (0=hr+her2…
5  75.0      1       1        0    0       Inf            NA  NA      sg1$`Molecular type (0=hr+her2…
```

Comment: If you look at the source code for `broom:::tidy.survfit` you'll see it does nothing more than extract the components as shown in other answers here. There's not really much reason to install this plus all its dependencies (and there are plenty) for simple object extraction and data frame construction.

Comment: I agree with you, just an alternate approach to remember just in case we may need it for other models especially when working with tidymodels